# Show that there exists a point

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^1$ class function such that $f(0)=0$ and there exists $a\in (0,1)$ with $f(a)f'(a)<0$.
>   Show that there exists $b\in(0,1)$ such that $f'(b)=0$

I tried to consider the function $g(x)=[f(x)]^2$.But not getting the result!

Comment: @julien for which a you have $f(a)f'(a)<0$?

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini Oh, boy...Time to switch to cooking.se.

Comment: @julien - ignore my comment - I misread the end of the question as $f(b)$ not $f'(b)$.

Comment: Consider the two cases: $f(a)>0$ and $f(a)<0$.

Comment: Considering $g=f^2$ as you suggest, you can treat both cases simultaneously. Consider a point where $g$ achieves its maximum over $[0,a]$ and see why the assumptions imply that $g(b)>0$ and $b\in (0,a)$. Whence $g'(b)=0\Rightarrow f'(b)=0$.

Answer (score 2):

You have two ways to make $f(a)f'(a)$ negative - either $f(a)$ is negative and $f'(a)$ is positive, or vice-versa.
If the former, then this means that $f(x)$ has been decreasing at some point (it started at zero and is now negative), and hence that there is some $c \in (0,1)$ such that $f'(c) <0$. But we also have that $f'(a) >0$. Moreover, we have that $f'$ is continuous, and hence by the intermediate value theorem there is a point in between $a$ and $c$ such that $f'$ is zero. Call this point $b$.

The other case is symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f(a)>0$. The function $f$ has a maximum over the interval $[0,a]$ in a point $b$. But since $f'(a)<0$ we have that $b\neq a$ and since $f(a)>f(0)$ we have that $b\neq 0$ so $b\in (0,a)$ and $f'(b)=0$.

One can make a similar reasoning (with the minimum instead of maximum) when $f(a)<0$.